# Use Linq to SQL to create unique list of numbers by merging two integer fields

Tags: c#, linq

I am using MVC and EF code first to access a SQL Server table that contains two int fields

For example:

```
F1  F2
1   2
2   3
3   4
```

From this, how would I use Linq to SQL (or anything else) to produce a list containing 1,2,3,4

Any suggestions preferably in C# would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does 1,2,3,4 mean? A list of all unique numbers? A path in a graph for which this is a neighbor table? Please clarify.

Comment: whats the entity called?

Comment: Just FYI; LINQ to SQL is something different; you mean LINQ to Entities.

Answer (score 4):

```
var items = Table.Select(t=>t.F1)
                 .Union(Table.Select(t=>t.F2))
                 .ToList()
```

Comment: same as my answer but faster (+1.)

Comment: Smashing - this worked perfectly. Thanks to Adrian, Olivier and Chuck.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Union`. It will merge two objects and remove duplicate values. note that you have no need to use `.Distinct()` in this case, because `Union` remove duplicate values by default.

```
var mergedList = myEntity.Select(p=>p.F1).
                 Union(myEntity.Select(p=>p.F2)).ToList();
```

Comment: F1 and F2 are attributes (columns), not entities

Comment: I wrote it in generic way, where F1 and F2 are your objects. But if you want, I've edited my answer for entities.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1.Union(list2).Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var result = source
    .Select(s => s.F1)
    .Union(
        source.Select(s => s.F2)
    );
```

Note that `Union` returns the elements from both input sequences, excluding duplicates. You also might want to add a `.OrderBy(x => x)` if the elements need to be ordered.

Comment: Very helpful suggestion. I will add that. Thanks Olivier.